# decision tree in R- extract data from a specific branch

Tags: decision-tree, extract, rpart, party

I am trying to build a classify decision tree using rpart and partykit, and I am wondering is there any function within those packages (or any packages, for that matter) to allow me to create a dataset containing data from a specific subtree or branch?

I know that I can manually create the subset from original data set with DT rules, but I am trying to automate certain process and finding that function will help me immensely.

Example:

```
library (rpart)
library(partykit)

data("Titanic", package = "datasets")
ttnc <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
ttnc <- ttnc[rep(1:nrow(ttnc), ttnc$Freq), 1:4]
names(ttnc)[2] <- "Gender"

rp <- rpart(Survived ~ Gender + Age + Class,  data = ttnc)
prp <- as.party(rp)

prp[5]
```

Lets say that I wanna extract data from the subtree #5,  is there any function within those packages that allow me to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the solution posted by @JakobGepp you can use the `data_party()` function provided by `partykit`:

```
data_party(prp, id = 5)
```

Essentially, this does the same thing internally that Jakob did explicitly by hand.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Comment: You're very welcome. If my and Jakob's answer were useful for you, please consider upvoting them :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you meant this by using the DT rules, but you could use the `predict()` function of the partykit package to predict the node / branches and then split the data according to your subtree.

```
ttnc$Node <- predict(prp, newdata = ttnc, type = "node")

subtree <- subset(ttnc, Node == 5)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I am looking for!